# Why isn't EventArgs an interface instead of a class?

Tags: c#, .net

Back in the old days when they were designing a common style of raising and handling events, why did they decide to make `EventArgs` a class? It's completely empty, without any common code, so why would it NOT be an interface?

**What are the advantages an empty class here has compared to an empty interface?**

By making it a class, they took all the restrictions that come with a class (i.e. no multiple inheritance), without leveraging any of its benefits (i.e. providing some common behavior).

Why didn't they make the convention something like this? There's a delegate with an empty interface parameter and an implementation of that interface representing an event with no extra information.

```
public interface IEventArgs { }

public class EventArgs : IEventArgs
{
    public static EventArgs Empty { get { return _empty; } }
    private static EventArgs _empty = new EventArgs();
}

public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, IEventArgs e);
public delegate void EventHandler<T>(object sender, T e) where T : IEventArgs;
```

#### Example

Let's say you have two events with the established convention:

```
public event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> ReceivingMessage;
public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> DroppingMessage;

public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public StringEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public string Data { get; private set; }
}
```

Now imagine you want to add cancellation ability to the `DroppingMessage` and string data to the `ReceivingMessage` event handlers. Unless you want to make it a breaking change, this is the only way to do it:

```
public event EventHandler<CancelStringEventArgs> ReceivingMessage;
public event EventHandler<StringCancelEventArgs> DroppingMessage;

public class CancelStringEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    public CancelStringEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public string Data { get; private set; }
}

public class StringCancelEventArgs : StringEventArgs
{
    public StringCancelEventArgs(string data) : base(data) { }

    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}

public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public StringEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public string Data { get; private set; }
}
```

You now have two classes with identical behavior and duplicate code, and you have to go digging through thesaurus to think of new and creative ways to differently name these same classes. Plus you're making your users curse your heritage (or inheritance, pardon the pun) because they have to be aware of these differences in identical classes.

Interfaces, on the other hand, would just mean taking this original code...

```
public event EventHandler<ICancelEventArgs> ReceivingMessage;
public event EventHandler<IStringEventArgs> DroppingMessage;

public interface IStringEventArgs : IEventArgs
{
    string Data { get; }
}
public class StringEventArgs : IStringEventArgs
{
    public StringEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public string Data { get; private set; }
}
```

...and adding just slight non-breaking changes:

```
public event EventHandler<IStringCancelEventArgs> ReceivingMessage;
public event EventHandler<IStringCancelEventArgs> DroppingMessage;

public interface IStringEventArgs : IEventArgs
{
    string Data { get; }
}
public interface IStringCancelEventArgs : IStringEventArgs, ICancelEventArgs { }
public class StringEventArgs : IStringCancelEventArgs
{
    public StringEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public string Data { get; private set; }
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}
```

As a side note, specifying it as an interface would also allow for covariance in generic interfaces with convention-compliant events. This feature of interfaces wasn't available at the time, however, so I get why it wasn't taken into account. Though it still saddens me. :(

Comment: I think you may have answered it yourself. Neither the interface features or generics were around in .NET when EventArgs was created, so the EventHandler<T> was not available either.  I imagine now it's an issue of backwards compatibility.  Using EventArgs is convention, but not required. You can pass your own class as well.

Comment: @phil Still, they did have interfaces at the time, right? So why use an empty class?

Comment: @phil Generics didn't exist in C# 1.0, but interfaces most certainly did.

Comment: Sure interfaces existed, but if they used an interface instead of a base class, it would be empty(a marker) and you would have to implement a class each time you wanted an empty event. I think using a base class is a bit easier for events that are just signals with no data.

Comment: @phil They could have still provided the default empty EventArgs class which implements this interface, as I have shown in my question. What I don't understand is why force all convention-complying code to inherit from this class instead of implementing a common interface.

Answer (score 3):

I can only speculate at this point (I don't have access to a copy of the annotated base class library right now). The main reason to me is to define an inheritance chain. Yes, `EventArgs` acts as the base and doesn't provide any functionality itself. Now, examine `CancelEventArgs`. It does provide some functionality (namely, provides a `Cancel` property and an additional class constructor). But, this class also acts as a base class to a number of child classes such as `DoWorkEventArgs`.

In essence, the base `EventArgs` class simply acts as a common, dependable base class for all event arguments. You could write code that only needs to consider intermediate class properties (like `Cancel`).

Comment: This answers the first part of my original question, thanks. Unfortunately, I removed that part of the question as it was deemed too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction for `TEventArgs` to have `EventArgs` as base class has been removed with .NET 4.5 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110). So now it's exactly the same as you wish.

But I guess it was done so due to the fact that interface is useless in this situation. `EventArgs` or `IEventArgs` is just a marker for developers to spot event data class easily. Even if it was an interface, you wouldn't use it. As your subscriber will expect concrete final type inherited from `IEventArgs`, not interface itself. So this interface would just add unnecessary additional type declaration since you need `EventArgs` anyway to simulate empty data.

Comment: This is interesting, I wasn't aware of it. However, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133(v=vs.140).aspx still says never to suppress the code analysis warning. So even though they still insist on using EventArgs, they made breaking the rule a bit easier.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect my personal opinion re this. I guess it's just a convenient convention, no more.

Comment: I have clarified my question to stress the advantage of using empty interfaces as markers as opposed to empty classes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers: `EventArgs` isn't totally without any functionality - it provides the static `EventArgs.Empty` member which is a uniform way for raising events without data.

Comment: My proposed interface-based convention also includes a class which implements the interface and has a static .Empty member. So no functionality gets dropped, just some restrictions.